# Is it possible to debug locally WebService on Google App Engine

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine

I am new on web services development and I will be using the app engine.

I would like to know if it is possible to debug locally a web service (at localhost:8888/) and debug at the same time the web app that will be using the service.

Comment: You should be more specific about the problems here. Like what kind of web service you want to build. Did you actually try to do something before positing here.

Comment: The general answer is yes, but knowing in what language you're coding your client (probably javascript?) and server (python, Java, or Go) will help people give you specific recommendations.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to web programming. I'll be using Google Web Tool Kit for the client.

Many thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

The App Engine SDK ships with a local server implementation that you typically debug on.  You'd debug the web app in your browser.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can debug both client and server.

However I assume that client and server are separate code bases - in this case you would have two IDE projects open each running it's own debug session.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to GAE, I would advice to use one of rich IDE's available out there. For example, I can mention Eclipse or IntelliJ which make it very easy to debug and find issues in GAE apps.

Here are some links:

- [Intellij GAE support](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_app_engine.html)
- [Eclypse GAE plugin](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse.html)